# Как скрыть API_KEYS в публичном репозитории Github?

Tags: github

Планируется проект использующий API различных сторонних сервисов. Работа планируется в команде, поэтому нет возможности просто создать .env со всеми api_keys и добать его в .gitignore, чтобы работать на одной локальной машине.
Я попробовал создать гитхаб сикрет: в Settings -> Secrets-> Actions secrets -> New repository secret, но теперь я не понимаю как связать его со своей локальной версией проекта.
Как мне их связать между Repository secret и мою локальную машину?
Является ли использование githab secret лучшей идеей для сокрытия api_keys  в репозиториях?

Answer (score 1):

Создать файл какой-нибудь app.config и туда добавить api кеи, и добавить его в .gitignore, читать из него ключи.

Comment: А как тогда другой человек не зная api кейз сможет работать над проектом на своей локальной машине?

Comment: @DmitriyBegishev, как вариант получать их через авторизацию с подключением на сервере с логином и паролем